# Symfony - postgrsql connexion failed because of the driver

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, wamp

I'm a newbie with php, symfony and postgresql. I try to do this project for a job interview.

I have installed: php 7.4 and symfony 5 and postegreSQL 13 (manage with pgAdmin) and use wamp64server.

In my project folder when I try to connect my symfony project to my postgresql database that I created,
I tried this command : bin/console make:migration after created an entity but I have this answer error:

[image: here my errors]

And here my doctrine.yaml code :

```
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: pdo-pgsql
        server-version: '13'
        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Do you an idea about what happen there ? I already tried to activate the extensions pdo_pgsql in the php.ini, but it didn't work. Someone can help me ?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set driver to `pdo_pgsql`. And be sure that your `php.ini` have `pgsql` enabled (`extension=pdo_pgsql` uncommented)